# Turn HAML buttons into radio buttons

Tags: ruby-on-rails, haml

I have some ruby and HAML code that works by showing two buttons on the screen.  I want to change these to radio buttons.  This is the code that currently shows two buttons:

```
.row
  .col-md-6
    .input-group
      = render @audience, opportunity: :opportunity
```

What gets rendered out looks like this:

```
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-6">
<a class="btn btn-lg btn-block btn-default audience-tab active" data-value="consumer" data-remote="true" href="/opportunities/229/edit?audience=consumer">Consumer</a>
</div>
<div class="col-md-6">
<a class="btn btn-lg btn-block btn-default audience-tab " data-value="business" data-remote="true" href="/opportunities/229/edit?audience=business">Business</a>
</div>
</div>
```

I don't need that href= stuff.  Not sure why that is there.  But what I want to get rendered out is two radio buttons that say "Consumer" and "Business" with a label that says "Audience Type".  Something like this should work:

```
  Audience Type: 
  <input type="radio" name="audience" value="consumer"> Consumer
  <input type="radio" name="audience" value="business"> Business
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I see you use Bootstrap, so HAML code should look like:

```
%p Audience Type:
.radio
  %label
    %input{name: "audience", type: "radio", value: "consumer"}
    Consumer    
.radio
  %label
    %input{name: "audience", type: "radio", value: "business"}
    Business
```

If `@audience` is a instance of `Audience` class you must place HAML code into `app/views/audiences/_audience.haml` template.

Comment: So this works and renders correctly.  But it is just static.  Sorry I didn't mention that this is an edit form.  So after the user enters a value and hits save, the next time they pull up the page it is supposed to remember that they chose "Consumer" and have it already pre checked.  I was hoping that first bit of code I published would give someone insight into how to set this up and make it dynamic.  I really am not familiar with what this specifically means.  = render @audience, opportunity: :opportunity

Comment: You need to place this code into `form` tag and create action to save this data in your controller.